# 2D Pathfinding with variable movement speed?

Tags: python, 2d, path-finding

Hi I'm pretty new to the path-finding field and I have searched all around the interwebs for an answer to my question so I figured its time to ask the experts:

My environment consists of a 2D rectangular map with walls and units to traverse the environment 
(no collision between units but they can't go through walls)
Units in the environment move in a turn-based fashion in a straight line but they can move at a speed of 
0 to unit.movespeed (e.g. 5)(you have control over the movespeed for every movement). (map size is range is from 20,20 to 200,200 cells but you can move to floating-point locations add walls can be at a location like eg wall[(x=10.75,y=9.34),(x=33.56,y=62.43])

In summery every tick, you tell a unit to move to a destination (x,y) of type float

I have tried A* and [goal-based vector pathfinding](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-goal-based-vector-field-pathfinding--gamedev-9007) algorithms but the problem I keep running into is figuring out how fast they should move because obviously, the optimal movespeed should be the maximum speed yet if they always move at the maximum speed they are prone to hit a wall because these algorithms don't take into account variable movement speed.
Any Ideas?
image of movespeed issue with a* star and goal-based vector pathfinding problem

[image]

Code:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self,coords,vector=None,distance=None,obstacle=False):
        self.coords = coords
        self.vector = vector
        self.distance = distance
        self.obstacle = obstacle
class VectorMap:

    def __init__(self,unit, dest, map=HardCoded._make_map()):
        self.size = Coords(len(map), len(map[0]))
        self.map = map
        VectorMap.map_converter()
        self.unit = unit
        self.dest = dest

    def _create_vector_map(self):
        return self._cell_def(1,self.map[self.dest])

    def _cell_def(self,dist,current_cell):
        neighbors = [Coords(0, 1), Coords(0, -1), Coords(1, 0), Coords(-1, 0), Coords(1, 1), Coords(1, -1),
                     Coords(-1, 1), Coords(-1, -1)]
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            #check if out of range of arr then return map
            if current_cell.coords.y + neighbor.y < self.size[1] and current_cell.coords.x + neighbor.x < self.size[0]:
                neighbor_cell = self.map[current_cell.coords.x + neighbor.x][current_cell.coords.y + neighbor.y]
            if neighbor_cell.obstacle:
                continue
            neighbor_cell.distance = dist
            #neighbor_cell.vector = current_cell
            return self._cell_def(self.map,dist+1,neighbor_cell)

    def map_converter(self):
        nmap = []
        for x,element in enumerate(self.map):
            tmap = []
            for y,value in enumerate(element):
                tmap.append(Cell(Coords(x,y),vector=None,distance=None,obstacle=False if value == 0 else True))
            nmap.append(tmap)
        self.map = nmap
        self._create_vector_map()
        for x,c in enumerate(self.map):
            for y,cell in enumerate(c):
                cell.vector = Coords(0,0)
                right_tile_distance = (self.map[x+1][y].distance if x+1 < self.size.x else self.map[x][y].distance)
                up_tile_distance = (self.map[x][y+1].distance if y+1 < self.size.y else self.map[x][y].distance)
                cell.vector.x = (self.map[x-1][y].distance if x is not 0 else self.map[x][y].distance) - right_tile_distance
                cell.vector.y = up_tile_distance - (self.map[x][y-1].distance if y is not 0 else self.map[x][y].distance)
                if cell.vector.x == 0 and right_tile_distance < self.map[x][y].distance:
                    cell.vector.x = 1
                if cell.vector.y == 0 and up_tile_distance < self.map[x][y].distance:
                    cell.vector.y = 1


                cell.vector = Util.normalize(cell.vector)


    def vetor_move(self):
        vector = self.map[self.unit.coords.x][self.unit.coords.y].vector
        movespeed = self.desired_movespeed()
        dest = Coords(vector.x * movespeed,vector.y * movespeed)
        return Action(mechanic='move', params=[dest], report='Moving With Maths')

    def desired_movespeed(self):
        pass

class Util:
    @staticmethod
    def normalize(vector):
        norm=np.linalg.norm(vector,ord=1)
        if norm == 0:
            norm = np.finfo(vector.dtype).eps
        return Coords(*(vector/norm))
```